# How to compare Fortran c_ptr with null

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I've got some Fortran and C code that need to be combined.

I'm using a Fortran interface that looks mostly like this:

```pascal
module bridge
  use, intrinsic::iso_c_binding, only : c_ptr, c_null_ptr
  implicit none

  type(c_ptr) :: instance

  interface

    function c_init() result(this) bind(C, name="bridge_init")
      import
      type(c_ptr) :: this
    end function c_init

  end interface

contains

    subroutine init() 
      instance = c_init()
    end subroutine init

end module bridge
```

My problem is that I'd like to put a check for initialization in the `init` subroutine, something like

```pascal
subroutine init()
  if( instance .eq. c_null_ptr ) then
    instance = c_init()
  end if
end subroutine
```

But this gives me a `Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: BLOCK BLOCKDATA PROGRAM MODULE TYPE INTEGER REAL COMPLEX BYTE CHARACTER CLASS` followed by `This binary operation is invalid for this data type.`

So what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use the `c_associated` function from the `iso_c_binding` intrinsic module. With one argument it checks for null

```pascal
subroutine init() 
  if( .not. c_associated(instance) ) then
    instance = c_init()
  end if
end subroutine init
```

Comment: It is actually the same as with regular Fortran pointers. You also do not compare with `null()` but you call `associated()`.